# How to make this existing android project accessible for screen-readers?

Tags: android, accessibility

There have been many requests by the blind community at where I live to make the following project accessible with screen-readers such as talkback.
https://github.com/DrKLO/Telegram
This app is open-source so I plan to make an accessible variation for the blind users.
Of course the original app exists in the playstore but ninety percent of it isn't accessible.
For example: talkback can't read some of the buttons (it reads absolutely nothing when the focuse is on them) or it can't read chat list or even it can't read the chats itself and many many more.
I looked at the codes briefly but nothing appeared to be wrong with them.
Could you explain what is wrong with the codes and how to fix the accessibility issue?
Do I have to modify the xml files only or the java files have to be modified also?
Because as I said the messages in a chat isn't accessible despite they are only text and should be accessible with a screen-reader; the same applies to chat list and other things.

Comment: do you call `nonTextView.setContentDescription(contentDescription)`?

Comment: This question is too broad to be answered here. Please read the [developer guide for Accessibility](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/index.html).